# Как добавить только часть ссылок из админки?

Tags: python, django

Стандартная админка подключается с помощью `path('admin/', admin.site.urls)`. Как я могу добавить только конкретную ссылку, а не всю админку. Допустим добавление модели или редактирование. Для авторизации нашел метод `LoginView.as_view`. Нужен аналогичный метод, но для добавления модели.

Comment: Что значит, конкретную ссылку? каждую конкретную модель регистрируют в админке отдельно. Незарегистрированные модели не будут отображаться в ней

Answer (score 0):

в admin.py своего приложения зарегистрируйте свою модель (YourModel)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import YourModel

admin.site.register(YourModel)
```